# ActiveAdmin with I8n.js in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

I'm developing a Rails app with [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) and I'm using [I18n.js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) for js translations.

The **problem** is that to get I8n.js to work I have to set the language in every `.erb` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  I18n.defaultLocale = "<%= I18n.default_locale %>";
  I18n.locale = "<%= I18n.locale %>";
</script>
```

Witch works fine in the rest of the app (if I place it in the `application.erb` file) but I can't find a global place to put it so it can be shared across all my ActiveAdmin forms.

I don't really want to repeat the code in every form or modify the default ActiveAdmin `erb` (if possible).

So is there a way to share some erb code across all views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, I think: 
1. Put this code into the layout views
2. Put this code into the separate [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) and render it in each view (providing there are some problems with layouts)